# How is life as a PhD student in Germany?

Tags: phd, germany, work-life-balance

I have a PhD offer from a German university in Nanotechnology. It is a 3 year position (which is a short span). I would like to know how is the general experience of doing a PhD in Germany? Is it really hectic? I am focused and dedicated towards my work but want to spare time for other activities too. So, would really appreciate any insight into PhD student's life, thanks!

Comment: You mean academic life? Social life? Cultural life? What? We have no idea what you are asking. Doing a PhD in Germany is no different than doing PhD in any other country and depends on a matter of factors such as: the group, the field, the adviser etc. The question, as it is, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: 3 or 4 years is the normal timespan for a phd scholarship in Europe. Unlike the US, we assume that the candidates already hold a master, so there isn't much coursework and most of this time is devoted to research (and TAing/tutoring, in many cases).

Answer (score 2):

As said before, during your PhD you are not required to take any courses. 3 years fund is the norm. Extensions would be max to a forth year. If you stick to the time plan of your PhD you can pull it off if you have a guarantee that any technical difficulties can be managed in time. Make sure that the team you are joining have the necessary experience in the specific topic of your PhD so you can more likely find help if things go south. Also try to make a clear agreement with your advisor on sticking to the time plan or possibilities to extend the fund if necessary.